# How to pass shell variable or enviroment variable to Maven when run mvn test for MariaDB Connector J

Tags: maven, mariadb

When using Maven to run test for MariaDB Connector J, you can specify `dbUrl` using `dbUrl` option like follows:

```
mvn -DdbUrl="jdbc:mysql://myhost:3306/testj?user=myuser&password=mypassword" package
```

My question is how to pass the `dbUrl` value dynamically when running from shell, i.e. something like this:

```
export myUrl="abcd"
mvn -DdbUrl=$myUrl package
```

But this does not work. May I ask is there a way to pass shell variables when using `mvn` command?

Comment: See also [How to retrieve maven properties inside a JUnit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/247346/1744774) and [How to read Maven properties from JUnit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7903621/1744774).

Answer (score 0):

If you define a property on the Maven command line with `-Dname=value` it is meant to be used inside your project's POM. (BTW, you can also access environment variables directly there by using [`${env.<variable name>}`](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html#resource-filtering-sect-enviroment-variable)).

To pass system properties to your test code you can use the [Maven Surefire Plugin `test` goal's parameter `<systemPropertyVariables>`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#systemPropertyVariables):

> `<systemPropertyVariables>` List of System properties to pass to the JUnit tests.

according to the examples on [Using System Properties](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html):

```
  ...  
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <dbUrl>${dbUrl}</dbUrl>  <!-- if defined on Maven cmd line -->
        <!-- <dbUrl>${env.myUrl}</dbUrl>  if defined as env variable -->
      </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ...
```

Use [`System.getProperty("dbUrl")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) in your code then.

Comment: Hi Gerold, thanks a lot for the detailed explanation for the system properties usage. However, my case is kind of special, I cannot modify pom file or the test code. I have found a way to workaround this by make up the whole mvn command string first, then run it with sh. May I ask is this the only way if I cannot modify the pom file or test code?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for Gerold Broser for the detailed explanation for the system properties usage. However, my case is kind of special, I cannot modify pom file or the test code. I have found a way to workaround this by make up the whole mvn command string first by something like string concat, then run it with sh.